# add multidimensional array to mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi I'm having multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => uzsakymas
            [value] => title
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => preke
        [value] => name
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => kaina
        [value] => 5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => kiekis
        [value] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => preke
        [value] => name2
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [name] => kaina
        [value] => 5
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [name] => kiekis
        [value] => 5
    )

)
```

But when I try get values for adding to mysql I'm getting an error. What I'm doing wrong?

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
print_r($json);
foreach($json as $key => $name) {
    echo $name['preke'];
}
```

> Undefined index: preke in...

Comment: Have you tried `echo $name['name'];`?

Answer (score 0):

Echoing `$name['preke'];` won't get you very far. Try `$name['name'];` as `name` is the key.

Comment: In this way I can get all names, but how to get specific value by name?

Comment: Well, you can either have the 1st dim key as the name, or you will have to know the the 1st dim key. So for `preke`, the 1st dim key is 4. So if you do `echo $json[4]['name'];` that will return `preke`. Which also means you do not need a `foreach` loop, as you go directly to your desired value, and you don't need to loop through all of the elements.

Comment: it returns only names, but I need to get e.g all values containing name: preke.

Comment: It returns same value many time. eg `name2name2name2name2name2name2 not name1 name2`

Comment: That's because you have it in your `foreach` loop, which is looping through each element. So because there are 7 elements, it will run that code 7 times. Take the code out of the `foreach` loop. If you want to print all of the names/values then do as I previously said, `$name['name'];` **in** the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$name['name'];
```

your $name var is the array containing 2 associative entries: name , value;